# How to declare a POST request in Delphi REST Datasnap?

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo, datasnap

I'm trying to write a function that will insert informations in my database using JSON or multiple parameters in the URL.

I already managed to create a function that returns informations from my database to the client but not the other way. Every example I find explains how to creat a JSON but not how to receive it with System.JSON (Delphi 10.2)

Here is a code sample for a GET function actually working on my Datasnap :

```
function TDM_Test.DS_getArticles(pStock : String): string;
begin
  try
    VGOutils.PR_logs('Get all articles from table');

VGOutils.FU_CheckConnect('1234567890');

with VGOutils.SQ_temp1 do
begin
  SQL.Clear;
  SQL.Add('SELECT code, name, price, seller, departement FROM articles');
  SQL.Add('WHERE stock');
  ParamByName('stock').AsString := pStock;
  VGOutils.SQ_temp1.Open;
end;

GetInvocationMetadata().ResponseCode := 200;
GetInvocationMetadata().ResponseContent :=
  VGOutils.PR_JSON(VGOutils.SQ_temp1, ['code', 'name', 'price', 'seller']);

 except on E: Exception do
    PR_error(E.Message);
  end;

  VGOutils.PR_Disconnect;
end;
```

Now I need the client to send me new articles to `INSERT` in my database.

The only thing that I cant figure out is how to declare the function and it's parameters.

I want the client to be able to send me a JSON with this correct format

```
{"article":[{"code":"AAA","name":"car","price" : "10400.90", "sellers" : [{"seller1" : "Automaniac", "seller2" : "Autopro" }]}]}
```

Now I know how to parse it with `TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue()` by reading this [JSON RadStudio](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/JSON)

EDIT
If this JSON string is hardcoded it works fine with ParseJSONValue but if the string is taken from the URL my JSONstring only contains "]}" and obviously there is nothing to parse.

```
 function TDM_Test.DS_insertArticles(pUrlJsonString: String): string;

 // Hardcoded JSON string
 jsonString := '{"article":[{"code":"AAA","name":"car","price" : "10400.90", "sellers" : [{"seller1" : "Automaniac", "seller2" : "Autopro" }]}]}';
 JSonValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(jsonString);

 // String received in url
 jsonString := pUrlJsonString;
 JSonValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(pUrlJsonString);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way I wanted it to work by not using the string parameter of the function but instead using the `Custom body` by passing a JSONObject.
The method is `POST` and the content type is `application/JSON`.

```
function TDM_Test.DS_insertArticles(pUrlJsonObj: TJSONObject): string;

JSonValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(pUrlJsonObj);

// Retrieve data for database fields
artCode  := JSONValue.GetValue<string>('article[0].code');
artName  := JSONValue.GetValue<string>('article[0].name');
artPrice := JSONValue.GetValue<string>('article[0].price');

//... Proceed to INSERT SQL with these values
```

Comment: I tested it in Embarcadero REST Debugger and it works fine.